# example of infinite solvable groups

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a solvable group. It is a well-known Theorem that "the index of every maximal subgroup of $G$ is a power of prime or infinite".
I want to find an example of infinite case.

Comment: No. It is finite case!

Comment: Does this one give an example? Semi-direct product of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}^{\times}$: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/289990/85329

Comment: I can't believe the comment of the person who voted to close this.  Is there a mechanism for reporting clueless close votes?

Comment: @C Monsour I don't think so, but it should be possible to vote against closing.